# Performance issue on Python

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I am having a performance issue on Python. The snippet below has 4 nested loops iterating over an OrderedDict, **matrix_col** which has 11000 items in it. Another iteration goes over a defaultdict, **trans** which has also ~11000 items in it. Execution of this process is taking too long. I appreciate if anyone can advise how to improve the performance.

```
import string
from collections import namedtuple
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict
import time

trans = defaultdict(dict)
...
matrix_col = OrderedDict(sorted(matrix_col.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
trans_mat = []
counter = 0

for u1, v1 in matrix_col.items():
    print counter, time.ctime()
    for u2, v2 in matrix_col.items():
        flag = True
        for w1 in trans.keys():
            for w2, c in trans[u1].items():
                if u1 == str(w1) and u2 == str(w2):
                    trans_mat.append([c])    
                    flag = False
        if flag:
            trans_mat.append([0])

trans_mat = np.asarray(trans_mat)
trans_mat = np.reshape(trans_mat, (11000, 11000))
```

Here is its current performance. It is basically processing 2 items per minute. With this speed it will take over 5 days to form the matrix, **trans_mat**:

```
0 Tue Oct  6 11:31:18 2015
1 Tue Oct  6 11:31:46 2015
2 Tue Oct  6 11:32:19 2015
3 Tue Oct  6 11:32:52 2015
4 Tue Oct  6 11:33:19 2015
5 Tue Oct  6 11:33:46 2015
```

Comment: So why are you looping over all keys in `trans` and all items in `trans[u1]`, when you could just *test* for `u1` and `u2` being keys in the `trans` and `trans[u1]` dictionaries?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data, and what's going on in that ellipsis?

Comment: Hi Martijn, how do I get the value "c" in the last step if I don't iterate over **trans[u1].items()**?

Comment: If you're dealing with lots of numeric data to the point where performance is a concern, use either `numpy` and/or [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (`pandas` is probably better for you if you're using `OrderedDict` to hold a bunch of rows with various fields in some order)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't taking advantage of the fast lookup available to dictionaries. Finding a key in a dict is O(1). To fix this you just need to change your algorithm so you aren't iterating all the keys looking for the ones you want..

```
from itertools import product
trans_mat = [ [trans[u1][u2]] if (u1 in trans) and (u2 in trans[u1]) else [0]
                 for u1 in matrix_col for u2 in matrix_col ]
```

Comment: If he needs to get empty values then yes, that's a good solution.

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for the response. **matrix_col** is a sorted set of items of type "State". Here is an example of "State":    33.594994,-84.72793,9978.2,280,60,270 1**

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for the response. The reason why I am doing string conversion is because I need to form a sorted and consistent set of row and column labels for matrix operations. So, I am converting from "the other type" to String first, so that it is sortable. Then I am sorting based on keys and creating an OrderedDict. I am basically unable to sort if I don't turn it into String.

Comment: Use the same type for keys and for sorting-- make the keys strings too, if you think you must. And then use key lookups. You're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Why aren't State items sortable?

Comment: Chad, is the above code of yours single line? Would you please fix the indentation and post it? State items are sortable. Though the output isn't the same with string version of it. Sorted version of State is not in ascending or descending order. String version is. Here is sorted State:
    29.751171,-83.52246,31570.549,240,30,180 1 
    28.11402,-82.84962,31585.184,240,30,180 1
    29.377922,-83.41894,31574.24,240,30,180 1
and here is its String version:
    26.157999,-81.41012,18044.068,270,30,225 1
    26.145752,-81.27514,15716.095,270,30,135 1
    26.012232,-81.15401,12513.588,280,30,135 1

Comment: The above code is 3 lines. the formatting is correct (according to my personal style guide). As for the sorting issue.. you can always pass a key function to the sort or sorted methods to specify how you want your data sorted. You should not be representing them as strings unless it makes sense to do so (i.e. you shouldn't store it as strings, then convert it back from strings all the time or convert other things to strings to compare).

Comment: I was able to sort the type "State" and run your code as is. It works fine with small dataset. When I use with my data of 11000 rows and 11000 columns, it gives the following "Memory error": Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hmm_freq.py", line 289, in <module>
    for u1, u2 in product(matrix_col, matrix_col) ]
MemoryError

Comment: I edited the answer to not use product which should solve the memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without context it's hard to understand logic and what you are trying to achieve but you should considering changing algorithm to iterate over `trans` first and then check the `trans_mat`. Something like:

```
for w1, t_val in trans.items():
    w1_is_in_matrix_col = str(w1) in matrix_col
    for w2, c in t_val.items():
        if w1_is_in_matrix_col and str(w2) in matrix_col:
            trans_mat.append([c])
        else:
            trans_mat.append([0])
```

Theoretically you can use list comprehension here and that would give you some boost as well (*but minor comparing to current inefficiency*).